# Replacing first and last character of every word using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql

My question is somewhat specific, I'm not using any kind of code compiler to achieve the result in the title, I am using a IRC Client that allows the use of "Quirks" so the users can have specific mannerisms when chatting, like starting every word with an uppercase, or changing every "s" into a "2".
Problem is that I can't see the whole code so even though I'm not familiar with REGEXP_REPLACE it makes things harder to learn.

The client simplifies the whole coding process, here's a screenshot of the 
[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc2Zy.png)

Filling the text boxes with "^(\w)" and "upper(\1)" respectively makes the first character capitalized, "(\w)$" and "upper(\1)" does the same with the last character.
I've discovered that "\b(\w)" will uppercase the first character of every word, i've tried "\b(\w)%" for the last character but it didn't work, as there is some syntax error, probably...
So, how do I get every last character capitalized?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc2Zy.png): [image]

Comment: Try `(\w)\b` (also, `regexp-replace` is the wrong tag).

Comment: Works like a damn charm, and I'll look for some better tag then (probably written in sql, so I guess that works)
Thank you very much!